# How to reverse number groups inside a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string and I want the number groups inside be reversed, for example "this is number 123456 and the reverse is 654321" be changed to "this is number 654321 and the reverse is 123456" .
how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I searched through net , I finally got to this solution:

```js
function reverseNumberInString(str){
    let numbers = str.match(/\d+/g) || [];
    for(let i = 0 ; i < numbers.length ; i++){
        let x = numbers[i].toString().split("").reverse().join("");
        let s = str
        str = s.slice(0,str.search(numbers[i])) + x + s.slice(str.search(numbers[i])+numbers[i].length)
    }
    return str
}
```

**Might Be Interesting:**

The whole problem started with thermal pos printer. I had to send a string of hex codes to it for printing , but in my language (persian/farsi) it would print in reverse , so I had to reverse the hex string. but then numbers would be reverse (and of course English words!!) so I reversed the numbers (and for English letters just change `str.match(/\d+/g)` to `str.match(/\w+/g)`) in side the reversed string!

**Updated:**

I also found out that decimal number have problems too. so I changed the regex part to `str.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9.،,\/]+/g)`